# How can I customize header for static file on tornado server?

Tags: python-2.7, tornado

When I request to favicon.ico located on the static dir, the tornado server responses with Server Header(Server:TornadoServer/4.4.2).
I want to hide server name and version. How can I modify it?

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r".*", BaseHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            debug=True,
        )
```

I could hide the Server Header on the normal contents by this.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Server", "hidden")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado allows to change the default static handler class with [`static_handlr_class`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings) option in `settings`

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class HomeHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write('ok')

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            static_handler_class=MyStaticFileHandler,
            debug=True,
        )
        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, **settings)

class MyStaticFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Server", "hidden")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = Application()
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```